# Using Reactjs and Bootstraps to show one collapse content at a time

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-4

Using Reactjs and Bootstraps to show one collapse content at a time.

Here the code below uses jquery and bootstrap4 to show and hide a collapse content when each button is click one at a time
and is working fine.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>

  <meta charset="utf-8">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.6/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script>
$( document ).ready(function() {

  $('.collapse').on('show.bs.collapse', function () {

    // hide all accordion except the clicked one
    $('.collapse').not(this).collapse('hide');

  });

});

</script>



    </head>
    <body>


  <a href="#content1"  data-toggle="collapse">Content1..</a>
  <a href="#content2"  data-toggle="collapse">Content2</a>
  <a href="#content3"  data-toggle="collapse">Content3</a>
 <br>





 <div id="content1" class="collapse ">
<h1>Content 1 records</h1>

<a href="#content1" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="collapse">Close </a>

  </div>


 <div id="content2" class="collapse ">
<h1>Content 2 records</h1>

<a href="#content2" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="collapse">Close</a>

  </div>

 <div id="content3" class="collapse ">
<h1>Content 3 records</h1>

<a href="#content3" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="collapse">Close</a>

  </div>



</body></html>
```

Now I have to obtain its equivalents in reactjs. 
I have install Bootstrap and  Reactjs code shows collapse content each time
the button is click.

**Here is my Issue with Reactjs.** I want it to show as only one collapse content just like in jquery code above.
Please How do convert this jquery code to reactjs equivalents or is there any other options

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

  $('.collapse').on('show.bs.collapse', function () {

    // hide all accordion except the clicked one
    $('.collapse').not(this).collapse('hide');

  });

});
```

**Here is Reactjs Code**

```
import React, { Component, Fragment } from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import $ from 'jquery';



class Collapse extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
    };
  }





    render() {

      return (
        <span>
          <label>
            <ul>



  <a href="#content1"  data-toggle="collapse">Content1..</a>
  <a href="#content2"  data-toggle="collapse">Content2</a>
  <a href="#content3"  data-toggle="collapse">Content3</a>
 <br />


 <div id="content1" class="collapse ">
<h1>Content 1 records</h1>

<a href="#content1" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="collapse">Close </a>

  </div>


 <div id="content2" class="collapse ">
<h1>Content 2 records</h1>

<a href="#content2" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="collapse">Close</a>

  </div>

 <div id="content3" class="collapse ">
<h1>Content 3 records</h1>

<a href="#content3" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="collapse">Close</a>

  </div>



          </ul>
        </label>
      </span>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't use jQuery to achieve this. Usually React projects have issues with libraries that directly affect DOM elements. An example of can be seen here: https://coreui.io/demo/#base/collapse.html

Comment: Approach no three of the links works for me. Please update your solution so that i can accept it as the answer. Thanks Hamed. You really saved my life....

Comment: I'm glad it helped you. I posted the code below, in case someone needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a sample code showing how to do this:

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.toggleAccordion = this.toggleAccordion.bind(this);
    this.state = {
      accordion: [true, false, false],
    };
}

  toggleAccordion(tab) {

    const prevState = this.state.accordion;
    const state = prevState.map((x, index) => tab === index ? !x : false);

    this.setState({
      accordion: state,
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className='wrapper'>
                <div id="accordion">
                  <Reactstrap.Card className="mb-0">
                    <Reactstrap.CardHeader id="headingOne">
                      <Reactstrap.Button block color="link" className="text-left m-0 p-0" onClick={() => this.toggleAccordion(0)} aria-expanded={this.state.accordion[0]} aria-controls="collapseOne">
                        <h5 className="m-0 p-0">Collapsible Group Item #1</h5>
                      </Reactstrap.Button>
                    </Reactstrap.CardHeader>
                    <Reactstrap.Collapse isOpen={this.state.accordion[0]} data-parent="#accordion" id="collapseOne" aria-labelledby="headingOne">
                      <Reactstrap.CardBody>
                        1. Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non
                        cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird
                        on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred
                        nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft
                        beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
                      </Reactstrap.CardBody>
                    </Reactstrap.Collapse>
                  </Reactstrap.Card>
                  <Reactstrap.Card className="mb-0">
                    <Reactstrap.CardHeader id="headingTwo">
                      <Reactstrap.Button block color="link" className="text-left m-0 p-0" onClick={() => this.toggleAccordion(1)} aria-expanded={this.state.accordion[1]} aria-controls="collapseTwo">
                        <h5 className="m-0 p-0">Collapsible Group Item #2</h5>
                      </Reactstrap.Button>
                    </Reactstrap.CardHeader>
                    <Reactstrap.Collapse isOpen={this.state.accordion[1]} data-parent="#accordion" id="collapseTwo">
                      <Reactstrap.CardBody>
                        2. Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non
                        cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird
                        on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred
                        nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft
                        beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
                      </Reactstrap.CardBody>
                    </Reactstrap.Collapse>
                  </Reactstrap.Card>
                  <Reactstrap.Card className="mb-0">
                    <Reactstrap.CardHeader id="headingThree">
                      <Reactstrap.Button block color="link" className="text-left m-0 p-0" onClick={() => this.toggleAccordion(2)} aria-expanded={this.state.accordion[2]} aria-controls="collapseThree">
                        <h5 className="m-0 p-0">Collapsible Group Item #3</h5>
                      </Reactstrap.Button>
                    </Reactstrap.CardHeader>
                    <Reactstrap.Collapse isOpen={this.state.accordion[2]} data-parent="#accordion" id="collapseThree">
                      <Reactstrap.CardBody>
                        3. Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non
                        cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird
                        on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred
                        nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft
                        beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
                      </Reactstrap.CardBody>
                    </Reactstrap.Collapse>
                  </Reactstrap.Card>
                </div>        
      </div>
    );
  }

}

ReactDOM.render( < App / > ,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```css
.wrapper {
  margin: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/reactstrap/6.0.1/reactstrap.full.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/latest/css/bootstrap.min.css" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div id="root" />
```